# How to optimise this code Algorithmically? Number of ways to assign N subjects to N students?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

> Your task will be to calculate number of different assignments of n
>   different topics to n students such that everybody gets exactly one
>   topic he likes.
>
> Each test case begins with number of students n (1<=n<=20). Each of the next n lines contains n integers describing preferences of one student. 1 at the ith position means that this student likes the ith topic, 0 means that he definitely doesn't want to take it.

I was solving this by defining DP[i][mask] to represent the number of ways to form mask set using i elements only!

Here mask is a subset of Subjects which shows me how many and which subjects are taken.

The recurrence being

```
for(i=1;i<N;i++)    //Student
    for(j=1;j<(1<<N);j++)   //Subject Subset
    {
        for(k=0;k<N;k++)        //Selecting subject
            if( (j&(1<<k)) && A[i][k] )
                DP[i][j]+=DP[i-1][j^(1<<k)];
    }
```

i.e. Taking one subject from the i th student's favourite subject and recursing for the lower states!!

However, this is not enough as the complexity of the solution is O(2^N * N^2).

We need to bring down one N at least!

How do I reduce the complexity of this problem? Here is my Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long DP[20][(1<<20)+1];
int main()
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(;T;--T)
    {
        int N,i,j,k;

        scanf("%d",&N);

        int A[N+1][N+1];

        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        /*

        First of all let's think about the state!!
        DP[i][j] where i is the i th student I am considering j is a bitmask which tells me which all subjects are
        Done!!
        ********All Right************
        So what can the recurrence be..?
        traverse over the array A[i][]
        If We can use the k th element of i.e A[i][k].
        We need to try assigning it and Get the number of ways
        *********Seems Fine *********
        What will be the base case??
        When only one element left in the mask and i is 1 we won't traverse more down!!

        **OK**
        SO what is the topological order of DP states !>>>????

        I dont Know!! Let's think... Let me explain ummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        ummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        I am like calling a smaller i with smaller subset!
        for every i
            go in the order of increasing subsets

        I think that should work!! Let's see
        */
        for(i=0;i<(1<<N);i++)
            DP[0][i]=0;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
                    if(A[0][i])
                        DP[0][1<<i]=1;

        for(i=1;i<N;i++)    //Student
            for(j=1;j<(1<<N);j++)   //Subject Subset
            {
                DP[i][j]=0;
                for(k=0;k<N;k++)        //Selecting subject
                    if( (j&(1<<k)) && A[i][k] )
                        DP[i][j]+=DP[i-1][j^(1<<k)];
            }
        long long ans=0;

        for(i=1;i<(1<<N);i++)
            ans+=DP[N-1][i];
        printf("%lld\n",ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Problem Link in case you need it: [Spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ASSIGN/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ,
I figured it out that we can make the solution faster! This is how!!
We dont need to take care of the i loop ! Why??
If a mask contains i bits then only it can fetch us some ways to do else wise it is zero because one subject is to be assigned to each one!
So now , the recurrence changes to

for (Every bitmask)
Get the bit count of mask!(This is the only i associated with the mask). Each mask is associated with only one i due to above argument!!

Check  in all ways we can achieve the current state by giving all the favourable subjects to the student! Now it will lead to a mask of lower bit numbers which is also associated with unique i , specifically i-1 !

So now , that is great we can have a One-D DP over the situation...

```
for(j=1;j<(1<<N);j++)   //Subject Subset
     {
            DP[j]=0;
            i=__builtin_popcount(j);
            for(k=1;k<=N;k++)        //Selecting subject
                if( (j&(1<<(k-1))) && A[i][k] )
                        DP[j]+=DP[j^(1<<(k-1))];
    }
```

My AC CODE(Run time 0.78) with scope of improvements by preprocessing the bit count instead of __builtin_popcount()

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long DP[(1<<20)+1];
int main()
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(;T;--T)
    {
        int N,i,j,k;

        scanf("%d",&N);

        int A[N+1][N+1];

        for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
            for(j=1;j<=N;j++)
                scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);


        for(i=0;i<(1<<N);i++)
            DP[i]=0;
        DP[0]=1;

        for(j=1;j<(1<<N);j++)   //Subject Subset
             {
                    DP[j]=0;
                    i=__builtin_popcount(j);
                    for(k=1;k<=N;k++)        //Selecting subject
                        if( (j&(1<<(k-1))) && A[i][k] )
                                DP[j]+=DP[j^(1<<(k-1))];
            }

        long long ans=0;
        printf("%lld\n",DP[(1<<N)-1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In comparison to optimised code by @Peter. He was able to optimise it to pass the time limit Run Time 2.60 sec  on test data by spoj!

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long DP[20][(1<<20)+1];
int main()
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(;T;--T)
    {
        int N,i,j,k;
        int masks[20];           // ADDED

        scanf("%d",&N);

        int A[N+1][N+1];

        for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
            masks[i] = 0;
            for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
                scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
                masks[i] |= A[i][j]<<j; // ADDED
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<(1<<N);i++)
            DP[0][i]=0;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
                    if(A[0][i])
                        DP[0][1<<i]=1;

        for(i=1;i<N;i++)    //Student
            for(j=1;j<(1<<N);j++)   //Subject Subset
            {
                long long t = 0;           // ADDED
                int mask = j & masks[i];   // ADDED
                while(mask) {              // ADDED
                  int bit = mask & -mask;  // ADDED
                  t += DP[i-1][j - bit];   // ADDED
                  mask -= bit;             // ADDED
                }                          // ADDED
                DP[i][j]=t;                // ADDED
            }
        long long ans=0;

        for(i=1;i<(1<<N);i++)
            ans+=DP[N-1][i];
        printf("%lld\n",ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two techniques you can use to reduce the time complexity:

- Meet at the middle
- Breath first search

So, we notice that, for first ith person, we don't need all n bit to be set, but just i bits to be set, so rather than iterating through all number from (0 to 2^n), we only need to iterating through all number that has i bits are set. We can do this by using BFS

Second, if we using one array `dp` to store the number of ways to assign subjects to first half n/2 people, and other array `dp1` to store the number of ways to assign  subjects to second half n/2 people, so the number of ways to assign subjects to all n people is

```
int x = a number that has n/2 bit set

int result = sum (dp[x] + dp1[2^n - 1 - x]);
```

Time complexity will be C(n, n/2)*n/2*n with n = 20 ~ 3*10^7 operations.

Comment: I think we can also improve this way  The subset alrready contains the information about the number of the student we are looking at!

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the speed (by a factor of 3.7 on my computer on the worst case input) with some bit hacking micro-optimisations on the inner loop.

The idea is that given a binary number such as 10100 you can extract a single set bit via the operation 10100 & -10100 = 00100.

We can therefore change the loop over k to only loop over important bits with this code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long DP[20][(1<<20)+1];
int main()
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(;T;--T)
    {
        int N,i,j,k;
        int masks[20];           // ADDED

        scanf("%d",&N);

        int A[N+1][N+1];

        for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
            masks[i] = 0;
            for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
                scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
                masks[i] |= A[i][j]<<j; // ADDED
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<(1<<N);i++)
            DP[0][i]=0;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
                    if(A[0][i])
                        DP[0][1<<i]=1;

        for(i=1;i<N;i++)    //Student
            for(j=1;j<(1<<N);j++)   //Subject Subset
            {
                long long t = 0;           // ADDED
                int mask = j & masks[i];   // ADDED
                while(mask) {              // ADDED
                  int bit = mask & -mask;  // ADDED
                  t += DP[i-1][j - bit];   // ADDED
                  mask -= bit;             // ADDED
                }                          // ADDED
                DP[i][j]=t;                // ADDED
            }
        long long ans=0;

        for(i=1;i<(1<<N);i++)
            ans+=DP[N-1][i];
        printf("%lld\n",ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I learn to write an optimised code? How do you know the performance of some operators over other?? And it indeed solves the problem!! And as I see it is merely changing the way of doing things rather than an algorithm!!

Comment: In general conditional code (if statements) are bad as they can cause the instruction pipeline to need to be flushed, and try to minimise memory accesses (or at least make them fit into the data cache)